# Google Chome and html2canvas - with CSS transform

Tags: jquery, css, openstreetmap, html2canvas

I'm trying to export OpenStreetMap actual screen of user and upload it on server. Everything should work, but I had to use CSS3 transform scale (0.5) on map, because of zoom things.

I was reading about html2canvas and "support" for Google Chrome, but even change from $(document).ready to load, or window.load, its not working.

Below: fiddle and screen from exported map from Google Chrome and Firefox...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit").on("click", function (event) {
            waitForIt();
        });
    });

    function waitForIt() {
        exportMap();
    }

http://jsfiddle.net/g7zbv045/
```

[firefox screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct32C.png)[firefox screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW6Xw.png)

Comment: second screen is google chrome

Comment: You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

found solution. before html2canvas set transform to none, after that transform with scale 0.5. only way to do that. – user3782638 just now   edit